# How to store node graphs in git

Tags: python, node-editor, export, geometry-nodes

I want to work on node graphs in blender together with other people. I need to have some mechanism of resolving conflicts. Ideally I would like to somehow store those graphs as code in a text file. Is there for example some way to automatically convert the node graph to txt file and then store it in git? Or maybe I could convert it to Python and entirely bypass the cumbersome visual programming?

Comment: You are looking for a technique that translates a node tree into a text file and vice versa? ...this is a very interesting question and I hope for a Python king who can answer it.

Comment: as far as i know, there is no automatic way to do this, you would have to write script that parses the node tree with python yourself with a text format (json, xml w/xsd, plain text, etc) and structure/naming you can agree with with your team. then you might also need to write a script that parses the file to populate the node editor so you could visualize it again.